# Python 'TypeError: not enough arguments for format string' when running mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table called 'authors' in database 'menagerie'.Which has two columns Id and photo.Id is INT and photo is BLOB.when I try to store image in to mysql database table I am getting Error as

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

My full code is

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","rset","menagerie" )
cursor = conn.cursor()


def read_file(filename):
  with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
      photo = f.read()
  return photo

def update_blob(author_id, filename):
  # read file
  data = read_file(filename)

  # prepare update query and data
  query = "UPDATE authors SET photo = %s WHERE id  = %s"

  #query blob data form the authors table
  cursor.execute(query, (author_id,))
  photo = cursor.fetchone()[0]
  cursor.close()
  conn.close()

def main():
 update_blob(1,"d:/Emmanu/project-data/bc1.jpg")

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following changes

```
query = "UPDATE authors SET photo = %s WHERE id  = %s"
cursor.execute(query, (data, author_id))
```

`%s` is a placeholder that is converted into a SQL literal to handle proper escaping (and avoid SQL injection).

Not sure what you were trying to do with `.format(data, author_id)`, and then providing `author_id` as a one item tuple in your original `execute` call, but see if the proposed changes work for you.

With these changes you would end up with

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","rset","menagerie" )
cursor = conn.cursor()


def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        photo = f.read()
    return photo

def update_blob(author_id, filename):
    # read file
    data = read_file(filename)

    # prepare update query and data
    query = "UPDATE authors SET photo = %s WHERE id  = %s"

    #query blob data form the authors table
    cursor.execute(query, (data, author_id))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def main():
     update_blob(1,"d:/Emmanu/project-data/bc1.jpg")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Now Error changed to 'TypeError: not enough arguments for format string' all othe traceback are same.

Comment: Can you update the question with your changes (below the original existing code) because you have something else wrong then.  I just tried this locally to make sure I didn't miss anything and it worked just fine.

Comment: Based on the updated question, you did not make the two changes?  What am I missing here.  You need to change the `query` assignment, and the `cursor.execute` call.